# change password when is set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to change password in my update method , when is $request->data['password'] is  set  and is not null
if is not set old password be replace
this is my code  but i'm faced with error !

```
             $user=Model::whereId($id)->update([
            "updated_at" => Carbon::now(),
            "department_id" => $department,
            "username" => $request->data['username'],
              'password'=>isset($request->data['password'])?bcrypt($request->data['password']):$user->password,
         ]);
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: *"but i'm faced with error !"* - What error?

Answer (score 0):

`isset` checks if the password field exists in the request but if it exists there and is null then it will still pass through. Also your ternary is the other way around.

you can use `empty` for what you are trying to achieve like:

```
          'password'=>!empty($request->data['password'])?bcrypt($request->data['password']):$user->password,
```

But if you want to use the ternary there then you must have retrieved your user model before that so your fallback actually has the value of the user password in the database. A similar approach is:

```
$user=Model::whereId($id)->first();

$user->updated_at = Carbon::now();
$user->department_id => $department;
$user->username = $request->data['username'];

if(!empty($request->data['password']){
 $user->password=bcrypt($request->data['password']);
}

$user->save();
```

That way you don't need a fallback. Returning the user model with the latest changes you can use the `fresh()` function after you `save()`

```
return $user->fresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution

```
$data = [
    "updated_at" => Carbon::now(),
    "department_id" => $department,
    "username" => $request->data['username'],
];
if (! empty($request->data['password'])) {
    $data["password"] = bcrypt($request->data['password']);
}

$user = Model::whereId($id)->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "dot" notation to access the arrays (like `name="data['password']"`) :

```
$password             = $request->input('data.password');
$model                = Model::find($id);
$model->username      = $request->input('data.username');
$model->department_id = $department;

if($password){
    $model->password = Hash::make($password);
}

$model->save();
```

You may use the has method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns `true` if the value is present on the request:

```
if ($request->has('data.password')) {
    //
}
```

Or use `whenHas`. The `whenHas` method will execute the given closure if a value is present on the request:

```
$request->whenHas('data.password', function ($input) {
    //
});
```